# Explode Array and store in db

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a problem exploding an array

Here's my code

```
 $arr1 = array();
        $i=1;
        foreach ($out1 as $value2){
             $arr1[][$i]= array_merge((array)$value2,(array)$detail);
              $i++;

        }
```

and this is the output

```
   Array(
    [0] => Array(
      [id] => 1234
      [name] => Rick Roll
      [dept] => IT)
    [1] => Array(
      [id] => 1234
      [name] => Dave Roll
      [dept] => IT)
     )
```

but when i try to explode the array it gives me error message
Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

here's the  code

```
$data = explode(","$array)
$q = "INSERT INTO  ".TBL_ARE_ENTRY."  VALUES(null,'$id[1]','$name[2]','$dept[3]')";
```

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: Post your expected output. And you can't `explode` an array. Post your attempts too

Comment: You `implode` arrays. `explode` turns a string into in array so it wants a string

Comment: If you want to store the array in db then use json_encode() and save it, while fetching use json_decode().

Comment: yuor array contains two sets by 3 values. But You use data 1 - 4. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `explode`. i think this is what you want:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO  ".TBL_ARE_ENTRY."    
VALUES(null,''$array[0][0]','$array[0][1]',''$array[0][2]')";
```

Comment: something like this actually hmm,

Comment: @seven you can then use `foreach` to get all values of the array